# Find and remove object in array by value in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with the following structure:

```
var questions = [
    {"answer":
        ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
    },
    {"answer":
        ["B1"]
    },
    {"answer":
        ["C1", "C2"]
    }
]
```

I also have an array of objects like below:

```
var answers = [
    {"value": "A1"},
    {"value": "A512"},
    {"value": ""},
    {}
];
```

For each object in `answers` (if it's not `{}`) I would like to find if the corresponding value appears in some object in`questions`. If it does, I would like to update a `counter` variable and remove that object from `questions`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? There is nothing special about this. Simply iterate and compare.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on which object to remove?  is it the entire answer object in the questions array, or for example the "B1" answer from the second answer object in questions leaving that object with an empty array?

Comment: You don't have a JSON array. You have a JS array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var questions = [{
    "answer": ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
}, {
    "answer": ["B1"]
}, {
    "answer": ["C1", "C2"]
}];
var count = 0;
answers.forEach(function(ans) {
    var flag = isExists(ans.value);
    flag && count++;
});
console.log(count);

function isExists(value) {

   return questions.some(function(ques) {
        var ind = ques.answer.indexOf(value);
        if (ind > -1) {
            ques.answer.splice(ind, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I think you're sort of missing the point of `.some()`. You don't need the `flag`. The `.some()` method itself returns `true` if you ever `return true` from the callback. So all you need is `return questions.some(function(ques) { return ques.answer.indexOf(value) > -1; });` And throw the `.splice()` back in if needed.

Comment: Perfect! +1 Now use `.reduce()` instead of `.forEach()` and you'll be an ECMAScript5 rock star! ;-)  `var count = answers.reduce(function(c, ans) {
    return c + (isExists(ans.value) ? 1 : 0)
}, 0);`

Comment: Thanks! I've been stuck on this for hours but apparently could not get how to write `.forEach()` and `.some()` right.